# MINIX stripped down shell example

Tags: shell, operating-system, minix

I came across a stripped down shell program in Tannenbaum's book on MINIX.

```
while(1) {
 read_command(command, parameters);
 if (fork() != 0) 
      wait(&status);    /* parent code */
 }
 else {
      execve(command, parameters, 0);  /* child code */
 }
}
```

When the infinite loop executes its first iteration, fork() will return 0 indicating it created a child process, when it executes the second time, wont fork() create a new child process ? How wait(&status) will ever execute?

I am new to understanding how an OS works/is built.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`fork` creates a new process *immediately*, so *both* processes see `fork` return, but with different return values. In the parent, the return value is the non-zero process ID of the child, so the parent executes `wait`. In the child, `fork` returns 0, so the child executes `execve`.